# C# Global hotkeys won't work in first minimize to tray but after showing and minimize again it works

Tags: c#, winforms, events, hotkeys, global-hotkey

Sorry If I miss anything like a fool, but I have to send in this project and I got a question

I have registered global hotkeys on handle created (EDIT!!)

```
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e) 
    {
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 1, 0x0000,0x70);
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 2, 0x0000,0x71);
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 3, 0x0000,0x72);
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 4, 0x0000,0x73);
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 5, 0x0000,0x74);
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 6, 0x0000,0x75);
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 7, 0x0000,0x76);
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 8, 0x0000,0x77);
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 9, 0x0000,0x78);
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 10, 0x0000,0x79);
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 11, 0x0000,0x7A);
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 12, 0x0000,0x7B);
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 13, 0x0002,0x45);
    }
```

and my button1 does hide the form and make the trayicon visible

```
    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        trayicon.Visible=true;

        ShowInTaskbar=false;
        this.Hide();




        trayicon.ShowBalloonTip(2000,"Corrector is now minimized","Right click at check symbol to Exit or show and change hotkey",ToolTipIcon.Info);
    }
```

I also have the function to show the form after double click on the tray icon

```
    private void trayicon_DoubleClick(object Sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        this.Show();
        Visible=true;
        ShowInTaskbar=true;
    }
```

Now the problem, I set global hotkey 13 to exit the program.

1.I opened the program , pressed Ctrl+E (the hotkey) >>> It does exit the program

2.I opened the program press button 1 then Ctrl+E>>> It doesn't exit the program

3.I opened the program,press button 1 and doubleclick the icon, the form show then Ctrl+E>>>> It does exit the program

4.I opened the program,press button 1 and doubleclick the icon, the form show then press button 1 again the form dissappeared then Ctrl+E>>> IT DOES EXIT THE PROGRAM.

That's why I am confused, 2 and 4 should have the same result but on 4 it does work while on 2 it doesn't work

Someone please help me

Thanks

Poom

Edit:!!

My Wndproc

```
     protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0312)
        {
            int id = m.WParam.ToInt32();
            if(id==14)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
            if(id==13)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
            if(check2==0)
            {
                this.TopMost=true;
                MessageBox.Show("กรุณาเลือกปุ่มที่จะใช้เเก้ก่อน,Select hotkey first","ข้อผิดพลาด",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                this.TopMost=false;
            }

            if(id==check2)
            {
            translate();//You can replace this statement with your desired response to the Hotkey.
            }

        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: Could be [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) ?

Comment: @Sinatr I don't think so, If because of that thing, why my second try works while the first time it doesn't

Comment: No idea, maybe something else gets focus? Just try it.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure your problem is tied to the constant toggling of the `ShowInTaskbar` property. To my knowledge, doing so destroys and recreates your window, meaning the handle you registered your hotkeys with is now pointing to the wrong thing.

As your code stands now, the hotkeys are only getting assigned when your form is FIRST created, since calling `Hide()` doesn't dispose of the window (For the record, the `Visible` calls are redundant; Show()/Hide() is equivalent to toggling `Visible` to true/false).

As far as I know, there are two ways around this. Either assign your hotkeys after a toggle on the `ShowInTaskbar` property, or override the `OnHandleCreated` method of your form and do your assigning there.

I am at a loss as to why your steps 3 and 4 work the way they do; I would figure they both **shouldn't** exit the program. Does this happen reliably? Perhaps someone smarter could venture a guess as to why it works. Is it possible the Handle is being recycled?

Comment: I'd rather create a separate window to register those hotkeys.

Comment: Certainly you could do that; The easiest fix for him, though, would be to just override the OnHandleCreated method and reassign for every ShowInTaskbar toggle, IMO.

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/?7xrcc0d0iby9rk1 a rar contain my program press the first button then you are at my problem form

Comment: Have you tried any of my suggestions? Don't take this personally, but I'm not going to execute your rogue executable. Your problem is understood; if you have more code to share or behavioral issues update your question with it.

Comment: @glace I had already overidden my onhandlecreated method Going to update the post

Answer (score 0):

I investigated the problem a little bit further (had the same problem) and saw that the window handle is destroyed right after you send the app to the tray and then immediately the window handle is re-created when i was sent to the tray:

1. `OnHandleDestroyed(EventArgs e)` invoked
2. `OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)` right afterwards invoked

Just re-register your hotkeys in OnHandleCreated callback and your hotkeys will work afterwards whenever you send your app to the tray.

PS: when you just minimize to the taskbar, your hotkeys will always work.

Regards